# Explicit injective generalization of map $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, combinatorial-proofs

I know a injective map from $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ given by the following explicit map:

$(m,n) \to \frac{(m+n)(m+n-1)}{2}+m$.

I am very curious to generalize it for $\mathbb{N^t} \to  \mathbb{N} $

I know there is a recursive map from, $\mathbb{N^t} \to  \mathbb{N} $, by using the map I have written from $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$. But I am interested to find out an explicit injective map from, $ \mathbb{N^t} \to  \mathbb{N} $, surjectivity is not necessary. Moreover, I do not want exponential maps. I am interested in a map that move as slow as possible.

Comment: If surjectivity isn't important, just use prime factorization: send $(a_1,...,a_t)$ to $\prod_{1\le i\le t}p_i^{a_i}$, where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime. (I'm posting this as a comment rather than an answer since I'm sure this question has been asked before.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber, Thank you for answering I forget to mention that I already know thin map but I want a map that move a bit slow as a comparison to this map as it is exponential map.

Comment: You should say that in the question, then.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, yes. I have edited it now. Thank you.

Comment: We tend to write this as $\mathbb N^t.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thank you I will edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a second thought, I think it's not that complicated.

We define $f(n_1, \dots, n_t) = \sum_{j = 1}^t \binom{\sum_{i = 1}^j n_i} j$. This is a direct generalization of the $t = 2$ case given in the question.

It is "easy" to check that this map gives a bijection from $\Bbb N^t$ to $\Bbb N$.

Comment: thank you for your idea. But I think it is a recursive formula that can be derived inductively by the case $t=2$. Actually, I need an explicit map.

Comment: This **is** an explicit map. E.g. for $t = 3$ you get $f(n_1, n_2, n_3) = n_1 + \frac{(n_1 + n_2)(n_1+n_2 - 1)}2 + \frac{(n_1 + n_2 + n_3)(n_1 + n_2 + n_3 - 1)(n_1 + n_2 + n_3 - 2)}6$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that "as slow as possible" is ambiguous but I take it to mean a bijection between $\mathbb{N}^t$ and $\mathbb{N}$.

We can "cheat" and use an exponential map to create a bijection $f(a_1,a_2,...,a_t):\mathbb{N}^t\to\mathbb{N}$. Define

$$S=\left\{\prod_{i=1}^t p_i^{a_i}:(a_1,a_2,...,a_t)\in\mathbb{N}^t\right\}$$

Note that every element in $S$ is unique and that $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Thus, we can order every element of $S$ in a strictly increasing sequence. Thus, define $f(a_1,a_2,...,a_t)$ as the position in this strictly increasing sequence of $\prod_{i=1}^t p_i^{a_i}$. For example, if we define $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,...\}$, then $f(1,1,...,1)=1$ for all $t$ (if we include $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$ then the smallest member of the sequence would clearly be the all zeros element). At this point, it is obvious that this function $f(a_1,a_2,...,a_t)$ is a bijection between $\mathbb{N}^t$ and $\mathbb{N}$ and that it grows as slowly as possible.

Comment: I think the OP means a polynomial map such as the example of $t = 2$ given in the question. It's possible to write down such maps for a particular $t$ (just immitate the $t = 2$ case, moving in the "antidiagonal" directions) but it would require some work to get a formula for arbitrary $t$.

Comment: @QC_QAOA, I like the idea very much. But I want an explicit map.

Comment: @WhatsUp, thank you for your comment. Could you please give me such a map even for $t=3$ and $t=4$ case?

Comment: @Manojupreti I think I got it and posted my answer.